# Как в js взаимодействовать с python

Tags: javascript, python

И так, я пишу скрипт для `Novoline` (не браузер) мне нужно передать переменную

```
var All = "Username: " + player.getName() + ";\n" + client.getVersion() + ";\nXZ " + player.getX() + " " + player.getZ() + "\n"
```

в `python` скрипт, и обработать уже в нём, как это возможно сделать?

Comment: неужели никак нельзя??(((

Comment: положите свою переменную в файл, или другое стороннее хранилище, ибо напрямую никак.

Comment: @Qwerty, в плане

Comment: Это вопрос?Как я понял у вы с js скрипта хотите передать значение в python скрипт, тогда сохраните переменную в файл(или другое сторонее хранилище) а в другом скрипте прочтите её оттуда

Comment: ага, как мне это сделать

Comment: как же мне это сделать?, ладно я нашёл способ как записать в файл, но как в python его просмотреть после записи